# Create user authentication using reactjs and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a web that using reactjs. I am an administrator and want to create user authentication and I use the admin.auth().createUser function but the error returned 'Module not found: Can not resolve' fast-crc32c '... node_modules \ hash-stream -validation

This is createUser code:

```
import admin from './fbAdmin';

export const createUser = (user) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();

        admin.auth().createUser(
            user.email,
            user.password
        ).then((resp) => {
            firestore.collection('users').doc(resp.user.uid).set({
                ...user,       
            })
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_USER', user });
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_USER_ERROR', err });
        })         
    }
}
```

And fbAdmin.js

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://fwslvtn.firebaseio.com'
});

  export default admin;
```

Error
[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to install fast-crc32c. npm i -s fast-crc32c

Comment: Have you tried with given answer?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. After install fast-crc32c, error returned: 
/node_modules/fast-crc32c/loader.js Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install fast-crc32c module to resolve the issue

```
  npm i -s fast-crc32c
```